# Getting row number for query

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have a query which will return one row. Is there any way I can find the row index of the row I'm querying when the table is sorted?

I've tried `rowid` but got #582 when I was expecting row #7.

Eg:

```
    CategoryID  Name            
    I9GDS720K4  CatA
    LPQTOR25XR  CatB
    EOQ215FT5_  CatC
    K2OCS31WTM  CatD
    JV5FIYY4XC  CatE
--> C_L7761O2U  CatF <-- I want this row (#5)
    OU3XC6T19K  CatG
    L9YKCYAYMG  CatH
    XKWMQ7HREG  CatI
```

I've tried rowid with unexpected results:

```
SELECT rowid FROM Categories WHERE CategoryID = 'C_L7761O2U ORDER BY Name
```

**EDIT:** I've also tried J Cooper's suggestion (below), but the row numbers just aren't right.

```
 using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Recipes AS t2             WHERE t2.RecipeID <= t1.RecipeID) AS row_Num 
                FROM Recipes AS t1 
                WHERE RecipeID = 'FB3XSAXRWD'
                ORDER BY Name";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recipeId", id);
        idx = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Why did you modify my query to `...WHERE t2.RecipeID <= t1.RecipeID`? In your question you are asking for the row number with respect to `Name` not `RecipeID` - that is why you are not getting good results, use `WHERE t2.Name <= t1.Name` instead

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a way to get the row number in **Sqlite**:

```
SELECT CategoryID,
       Name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM mytable AS t2
        WHERE t2.Name <= t1.Name) AS row_Num
FROM mytable AS t1
ORDER BY Name, CategoryID;
```

Comment: I feel like I'm doing something wrong or missing a behavioural quirk. The row numbers are all different, depending on which ID I use, but none of them are what I'd expect. Could it have something to do with using strings (TEXT) as the ID column?

Comment: Why did you modify my query to `...WHERE t2.RecipeID <= t1.RecipeID`? In your question you are asking for the row number with respect to `Name` not `RecipeID` - that is why you are not getting good results, use `WHERE t2.Name <= t1.Name` instead

Comment: This works fine, thanks. The key is to sort by the column in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a funny trick you can use in Spatialite to get the order of values. If you use the count() function with a WHERE clause limiting to only values >= the current value, then the count will actually give the order. So if I have a point layer called "mypoints" with columns "value" and "val_order" then:

```
SELECT value, (
SELECT count(*) FROM mypoints AS my 
WHERE my.value>=mypoints.value) AS val_order
FROM mypoints 
ORDER BY value DESC;
```

Gives the descending order of the values.
I can update the "val_order" column this way:

```
UPDATE mypoints SET val_order = (
SELECT count(*) FROM mypoints AS my 
WHERE my.value>=mypoints.value
);
```

Answer (score -3):

What you are asking can be explained in two different ways, but I'm assuming you want to sort the resulting table and then number those rows according to the sort.

```
declare @resultrow int

select 
      @resultrow = row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Name Asc) as 'Row Number'
from Categories WHERE CategoryID = 'C_L776102U'

select @resultrow
```

Comment: row_number() is not available in sqlite