# Updating all data in one column in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have data in sqlite database. Every data has `ID` which is primary key when I delete data from  database I want to resort `ID` of all data in a database.
For example,

```
+----+--------+
| ID |  NAME  |
+----+--------+
| 01 | Taylor |
+----+--------+
| 02 |  Mark  |
+----+--------+
| 03 |  Bell  |
+----+--------+
| 04 |  Jane  |
+----+--------+
```

Then I remove `02 | Mark` from a database and then a database must resort `ID` automatically.

```
+----+--------+
| ID |  NAME  |
+----+--------+
| 01 | Taylor |
+----+--------+
| 02 |  Bell  |
+----+--------+
| 03 |  Jane  |
+----+--------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know your use case, but changing the ID of records in the DB does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: Objective of data in the database is just for show on the screen and user can delete data from database.

PS. I just work with database for the first time. My method maybe wrong. You can give me the right method for this case.

Comment: You don't show the ID to the users, do you? so it does not matter if they are not contiguous. Just use the ID internally in your program to identify a certain record.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that. Don't change IDs in your database just because you delete records. Even though SQLite is not a "real" database - don't do that.

Instead, you can fetch the row number while querying your database. Based on the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151706/getting-row-number-for-query), you can do something like this:

```
SELECT id, name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table AS t2 
        WHERE t2.id<=t1.id) AS row_num
FROM table AS t1
ORDER BY id
```

NOTE: This query may become a performance issue if your table is large. Don't worry about it just yet, but keep it in mind.