# How to use ROW_NUMBER in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, row-number

Here is my query given below.

```
select * from data where value = "yes";
```

My id is auto increment and below there is result of given query.

```
id || value 
1  ||   yes
3  ||   yes
4  ||   yes
6  ||   yes
9  ||   yes
```

How to use ROW_NUMBER in sqlite? So that i can get result which is given below.

```
NoId || value 
1    ||   yes
2    ||   yes
3    ||   yes
4    ||   yes
5    ||   yes
```

ROW_NUMBER AS NoId.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151706/getting-row-number-for-query

Comment: Is `id` a autoincrement or a PK column? Have your tried `SELECT _ROWID_`?

Comment: @Scotch: It's not exactly duplicate, because the OP seems to be asking about the ROWID of a full table scan, rather than the ROWID of a specific query.

Comment: @AlixAxel So query the whole table?

Comment: @Scotch: The data seems to suggest that, yes. I know it's also possible to overcome that with the answer you linked to, but it might be unnecessary and slower (depending on the column definition for `id`).

Comment: That's true. I guess people should use something like that until somethhing like rownum or row number() is implemented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get rowNum like column in sqlite IPHONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023292/how-to-get-rownum-like-column-in-sqlite-iphone)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this query

```
select id, value, (select count(*) from tbl b  where a.id >= b.id) as cnt
from tbl a
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d0a2d/6)**

```
| id | value | cnt |
--------------------
|  1 |   yes |   1 |
|  3 |   yes |   2 |
|  4 |   yes |   3 |
|  6 |   yes |   4 |
|  9 |   yes |   5 |
```

Answer (score 41):

[SQLite Release 3.25.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_25_0.html) will add support for window functions

> 2018-09-15 (3.25.0)
>
> 1. Add support for window functions

---

[Window Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) :

> A window function is a special SQL function where the input values are taken from a "window" of one or more rows in the results set of a SELECT statement.
>
> SQLite supports the following 11 built-in window functions:
>
> **row_number()**
>
> The number of the row within the current partition. Rows are numbered starting from 1 in the order defined by the ORDER BY clause in the window definition, or in arbitrary order otherwise.

So your query could be rewritten as:

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS NoId
from data 
where value = "yes";
```

**[db-fiddle.com demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kUnajtCwrSZo9iNNTPXEXr/0)**

Answer (score 4):

The `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function can be done over an empty `ORDER()` like so (credit to @forpas):

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS NoId
from data 
where value = "yes";
```

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` will return an arbitrary row number. Also, it is not at all needed because just `OVER ()` will do the same.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, performance wise, `OVER ()` has no overhead while `OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` does, on top of it potentially returning arbitrary numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I mended somewhat with fiddleanswer and got exactly the result as expected

```
select id, value , 
       (select count(*) from data b where a.id >= b.id and b.value='yes') as cnt 
from data a where  a.value='yes';

result
1|yes|1
3|yes|2
4|yes|3
6|yes|4
9|yes|5
```

Comment: This only means, that there is no such functionality in SQLite. I wonder if this is O(n^2) by the way...

Comment: Yes, this is n^2-ish. Don't do it :)

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: sqlite3 version 3.25 now supports window functions including:

row_number() over(order by id)

[SQLITE3 Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM main AS t2
WHERE t2.col1 < t1.col1) + (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM main AS t3
WHERE t3.col1 = t1.col1 AND t3.col1 < t1.col1) AS rowNum, * FROM Table_name t1  WHERE rowNum=0 ORDER BY t1.col1 ASC
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].