# How to select one element from a group?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table `t` with columns `foo` and `bar`:

```
foo bar
a   x
a   y
b   z
```

I want to write something like

```
select foo, count(*) as num, SOMETHING(bar) from t group by foo;
```

and get

```
foo num bar
a   2   x    <--- or y, I don't care
b   1   z
```

I.e., `SOMETHING` should select an arbitrary value that appeared in a group (first, last, random - I don't care).

Is there a way to do it in `sqlite3`?

Comment: If you dont care why do you want it there?

Comment: Did you ever try `bar`?

Comment: @CL. no, and I am surprised and delighted that it works (I expected an error)! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly don't care, consider using `MIN(bar)` or `MAX(bar)`.  If you want it to be different each time, you'll need to number each value randomly and select the lowest corresponding value.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847574/how-to-use-row-number-in-sqlite) should help you if you choose that route.