# How to perform subquery in this case?

Tags: sqlite

So, let's consider my table as:

```
col1 data1 col2 data2
0     apple   1   frog
1     orange  0   dino
1     pine    0   dog
0     guava   0   cat
```

My result query should consist of `data1` and `data2` in a way that `col1=1`, then it shows that `data1` value, and same with `col2=1`, then shows `data2`.

Ideal output:

```
data1 data2
orange frog
pine   NULL
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: Can you explain why would you get null as opposed to pine frog? As col1 for pine is 1 so that matches col2 of apple frog. Which is possible.

Comment: Are the two pairs of columns independent of each other?  Sounds like an undesirable database design.

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible :) This sql will give you the result you want:

```
WITH t1 as 
(select rowid,col1,data1,
(select count(*) from thetable temp1 
  where temp1.col1 = tt.col1 and temp1.rowid < tt.rowid) seq1
from thetable tt
),
t2 as (select col2,data2,
(select count(*) from thetable temp2 
  where temp2.col2 = tt.col2 and temp2.rowid < tt.rowid) seq2
from thetable tt
)

select data1, data2
from t1
LEFT join t2 on col1 = col2 and seq1 = seq2
where col1 = 1
order by col1
```

The thought being:

- Split the col1 data and the col2 data into separate tables (t1, t2)
- Assign a sequence number (seq1, seq2) to each row. (With [props to @meherzad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847574/how-to-use-row-number-in-sqlite) for the subquery).
- Then use the left join to assign col2's to col1's until you run out.