# A join that "allocates" from available rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table X I want to update according to the entries in another table Y.  The join between them is not unique.  However, I want each entry in Y to update a *different* entry in X.

So if I have table X:

```
i (unique)  k           v         
----------  ----------  ----------
p           100         b         
q           101         a         
r           202         x         
s           301         a
```

and table Y:

```
k (unique)  v         
----------  ----------
0           a         
1           b         
2           a         
3           c         
4           a
```

I want to end up with table X like:

```
i           k           v
----------  ----------  ----------
p           1           b
q           0           a
r           202         x
s           2           a
```

The important result here is that the two rows in X with v = 'a' have been updated to two distinct values of k from Y.  (It doesn't matter which ones.)

Currently, this result is achieved by an extra column and a program roughly like:

```
UPDATE X SET X.used = FALSE;
for Yk, Yv in Y:
    UPDATE X
       SET X.k = Yk,
           X.used = TRUE
     WHERE X.i IN (SELECT X.i FROM X
                    WHERE X.v = Yv AND NOT X.used
                    LIMIT 1);
```

In other words, the distinctness is achieved by "using up" the rows in Y.  This doesn't scale well.

(I'm using SQLite3 and Python, but don't let that limit you.)

Comment: Are you using version 3.25 or later?

Comment: The trick here is you want to assign a row number to each v entry in tables y  an x based on the order of k and i (or some date order or whatever)   This would then allow you to join both on v and the row number ensuring each record is allocated.  This can be accomplished using a window function; but not available prior to 3.25.  So then the question becomes how do we simulate it in 3.0..  perhaps by... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847574/how-to-use-row-number-in-sqlite

Comment: SQLite version 3.22.0 (from the Ubuntu repo).  No window functions.  I'd like to avoid a custom local version but it's an option.

Comment: i is unique in this case, if that helps. No other combination of i, k, and v are unique.

Comment: A custom local version is the best way to use sqlite. That way you *know* you have the features you need available and aren't stuck on a random old version without optional modules you might want or newer features and fixes.

Comment: That rather depends on the way the software will be delivered and deployed, but I take your point.

Comment: It also eliminates a dependency if you distribute your application.

Comment: You'll need windowing functions for this, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by using rowids to pair up the results of a join.  Window functions aren't necessary.  (Thanks to [xQbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016435/xqbert) for pointing me in this direction.)

First, we sort the two tables by `v` to make tables with rowids in a suitable order for the join.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Xv AS SELECT * FROM X ORDER BY v;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Yv AS SELECT * FROM Y ORDER BY v;
```

Then we can pick out the minimum rowid for each value of `v` in order to create a "zip join" for that value, pairing up the rows.

```
SELECT i, Yv.k, Xv.v
  FROM Xv JOIN Yv USING (v)
       JOIN (SELECT v, min(Xv.rowid) AS r FROM Xv GROUP BY v) AS xmin USING (v)
       JOIN (SELECT v, min(Yv.rowid) AS r FROM Yv GROUP BY v) AS ymin
         ON ymin.v = Xv.v AND Xv.rowid - xmin.r = Yv.rowid - ymin.r;
```

The clause `Xv.rowid - min.x = Yv.rowid - min.y` is the trick: it does a pairwise match of rows with the same value of `v`, essentially allocating one to the other.  The result:

```
i           k           v         
----------  ----------  ----------
q           0           a         
s           2           a         
p           1           b
```

It's then a simple matter to use the result of this query in an UPDATE.

```
WITH changes AS (<the SELECT above>)
   UPDATE X SET k = (SELECT k FROM changes WHERE i = X.i)
    WHERE i IN (SELECT i FROM changes);
```

The temporary tables could be restricted to the common values of `v` and possibly indexed on `v` if the query is large.

I'd welcome refinements (or bugs!)