# Does Android Room Database Query support row_number?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room, row-number

I am trying to get the following sqlite query working in my android room database, but it's complaining with a couple of errors.

```
@Query("with cte as (\n" +
        "  select t.exercise_name,t.band, t.reps, t.weight\n" +
        "  from ( \n" +
        "    select *,\n"+      "" +
        "      row_number() over (partition by band order by reps desc) rnreps,\n" +
        "      row_number() over (partition by band, reps order by weight desc) rnweight" +
        "    from tracked_exercises\n" +
        "  ) t  \n" +
        "  where exercise_name = :name\n" +
        ")  \n" +
        "select * from cte c\n" +
        "where not exists (\n" +
        "  select 1 from cte\n" +
        "  where band = c.band and reps > c.reps and weight >= c.weight\n" +
        ")  \n")
List<TrackedExercise> getPersonalRecords(String name);
```

1 just before the bracket in front of partition `"<compound operator>, FROM, GROUP, LIMIT, ORDER, WHERE or comma expected, got '('"`

And another when I try to compile `"error: no viable alternative at input 'with cte as...."`

I have managed to get the same query working on fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ekNDkvnWCgRbAPabvkcmGY/8)

Is the `row_number() over (partition'` clause not supported by Room or am I missing something?

EDIT:
Just found this [Android Room + Window Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55067466/android-room-window-functions?rq=1) looks like this function is only avaliable in SQLite 3.25 and higher Android only goes upto 3.19. I'm still interested if anyone has any ideas on how to create a query that does the same thing without using Windows Functions

Comment: Sqlite supports row_number(). Maybe something else not supported, you can check all used operators if they supported by SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution to my problem using 2 CTE's then joining the results

```
@Query("-- gets the max reps at each set of exercise_name, band, weight\n" +
        "with repsCTE as (\n" +
        "  select *,max(reps) reps\n" +
        "  from tracked_exercises\n" +
        "  where exercise_name = :name\n" +
        "  group by exercise_name, band, weight ), \n" +
        "\n" +
        "-- gets the max weight at each set of exercise_name, band, reps\n" +
        "weightCTE as (\n" +
        "  select *,max(weight) weight\n" +
        "  from tracked_exercises\n" +
        "  where exercise_name = :name\n" +
        "  group by exercise_name, band, reps ) \n" +
        "\n" +
        "select * \n" +
        "from repsCTE r join weightCTE w\n" +
        "on r.id = w.id\n" +
        "order by band,reps" )
List<TrackedExercise> getPersonalRecords(String name);
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ekNDkvnWCgRbAPabvkcmGY/11)