# Sqlite Query: Five Most Recent Episode of Each Podcast

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

My application stores hundreds of podcast episodes in a SQLite table. I am looking for query that returns the five most recent episodes **for each** podcast (podcasts are stored in a different table).

The relevant table columns are

- `media_id` = primary key (unique identifier for an episode)
- `publication_date` = can be used find the most recent episodes
- `episode_remote_podcast_feed_location` = defines the relation to a podcast

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM episodes a
WHERE a.media_id IN (
    SELECT b.media_id
    FROM episodes b 
    WHERE a.episode_remote_podcast_feed_location = b.episode_remote_podcast_feed_location
    ORDER BY b.episode_remote_podcast_feed_location, b.publication_date DESC
    LIMIT 5
) 
ORDER BY a.episode_remote_podcast_feed_location, a.publication_date
```

The above query **always returns five episodes** (in total) - no matter how many podcasts I have. At least those episodes are all belonging to the same podcast. (Episodes have the same value for `episode_remote_podcast_feed_location`.)

**Needed solution:** I need a query that returns five episodes (the most recent ones) for each podcast. So if the application has only a single podcast stored, return five episodes. If the application has three podcasts stored, return 15 episodes: five episodes for podcast b, five episodes for podcast c.

**Additional information:** I need to able to use the query in an Android application. The version of SQLite bundled with Android is [not the most current](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary). Some SQLite features, for example Window Functions, are not supported on Android (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55069907/14326132).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` in a subquery to enumerate the episodes of each podcast, then filter on the top 5 per podcast in the outer query:

```
select *
from (
    select e.*, 
        row_number() over(
            partition by episode_remote_podcast_feed_location 
            order by  publication_date desc
        ) rn
    from episodes e
) e
where rn <= 5
```

In versions of SQLite that do not support window functions, an alternative is a correlated subquery:

```
select *
from episodes e
where (
    select count(*) 
    from episodes e1 
    where 
        e1.episode_remote_podcast_feed_location = e.episode_remote_podcast_feed_location 
        and e1.publication_date  >= e.publication_date 
) <= 5
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks great. I did not know window functions before. There is one problem. I am using SQLite on Android. And it seems that the SQLite version bundled with Android does not support window functions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55067466/android-room-window-functions). I will edit my initial question accordingly.

Comment: Your update solved my problem. Thank you. That was super helpful.