# How to get latest entry from SQLite3 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Suppose you have a database with just one column **i.e.** `ID`. If you want to select the latest 4 values entered in the DB file how would you do this? (I am using `SQLite3`)

What i did to get the latest 1 value from the DB :

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM classes")

for class_Names in cur.fetchall():
    pass

print(class_Names)
```

This returns me the latest value. What will i have to do to obtain latest 4 data from a database. 
What i tried as suggested by @Zaven Zareyan:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Crawl_jar\test.db')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM classes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4")

for class_Names in cur.fetchall():
    print(class_Names)
```

But it results in:

```
('tVe95H',)
('tVe95H',)
('tVe95H',)
('sng_c explicticon',)
```

Original table:

```
('_3wU53n',)
('_3wU53n',)
('_3wU53n',)
('_3wU53n',)
('_3wU53n',)
('_3wU53n',)
('_3wU53n',)
('_3wU53n',)
('_2yAnYN',)
('_2ISNhP _3AOFWO',)
('puxlXr',)
('_1Nyybr  _30XEf0',)
('_1Nyybr  _30XEf0',)
('iUmrbN',)
('_1Nyybr  _30XEf0',)
('_3BTv9X',)
('_1Nyybr  _30XEf0',)
('_3BTv9X',)
('_1xHtJz',)
('_3wU53n',)
('_1Nyybr _30XEf0',)
('_1Nyybr _30XEf0',)
('_1Nyybr _30XEf0',)
('_1Nyybr _30XEf0',)
('_1UoZlX',)
('_1p7h2j',)
('LM6RPg',)
('_3Wn9Gb',)
('_1Nyybr _30XEf0',)
('_3wU53n',)
('tVe95H',)
('tVe95H',)
('_3wU53n',)
('_3wU53n',)
('tVe95H',)
('_1Nyybr _30XEf0',)
('sng_c explicticon',)
('sng_c explicticon',)
('sng_c',)
('ellipsis-single ware-brand',)
('ellipsis-single ware-brand',)
('question-hyperlink',)
('question-hyperlink',)
('question-hyperlink',)
('excerpt',)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your id is auto-incremented int, you can do the following:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id FROM classes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4")

for class_Names in cur.fetchall():
    print(class_Names)
```

Comment: But how to get the latest 4 values from this?? @Zaven Zareyan

Comment: you can use `LIMIT 4` in your query

Comment: What do you meant by ```auto-incremented int``` ?

Comment: When you put record, it automatically gets id, the incremented id of last record.

Comment: Okay so it's not working. Just see my question again as i just edited...

Comment: You can try to use row_number, but it needs something to determine the order, do you have date_inserted column? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847574/how-to-use-row-number-in-sqlite