# Create auto-increment field in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, row-number

I am trying to create the correct select to have the row number for an ordered value in a table. Right now, the output does have the `row_num` field for the count but I would like to have the count sorted ascending based on on the `value` column *before* it is created.

If possible, how can this be done?

Existing code:

```
select id, value, (select count(*)
   from tbl b where a.id >= b.id) as row_num
from tbl a order by value asc
```

Current output (no ordering): [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/88a4ef/2)

```
id | value | row_num
1  | jbl   | 1
3  | bog   | 2
4  | tak   | 3
6  | oza   | 4
8  | ars   | 5
```

Current output (with ordering on value):
[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/88a4ef/5)

```
id | value | row_num
8  | ars   | 5
3  | bog   | 2
1  | jbl   | 1
6  | oza   | 4
4  | tak   | 3
```

Desired output:

```
id | value | row_num
8  | ars   | 1
1  | bog   | 2
3  | jbl   | 3
6  | oza   | 4
8  | tak   | 5
```

There is a similar thread ([How to use ROW_NUMBER in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847574/how-to-use-row-number-in-sqlite)) but the `value` col was not sorted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `row_number()` window function.

```
SELECT id
     , value
     , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY value) AS row_num
FROM tbl
ORDER BY value;
```