# sql lite getting row number and reset for each group

Tags: sqlite, row-number

already did searching for the topic , and got thread and try to modified to my needed but it end with stuck.

From this link 
[Getting row number for query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151706/getting-row-number-for-query)

i try to get rownumber reset for each group...

**example :**

`LetterNumber | DateLetter | ToLetter | Row
AA-010-2018  | 2018-09-01 |  Jon     | 1
AA-010-2018  | 2018-09-01 |  Dian    | 2
AA-010-2018  | 2018-09-01 |  Jajang  | 3
BB-011-2018  | 2018-09-01 |  Julaeha | 4
BB-011-2018  | 2018-09-01 |  Endang  | 5
BB-011-2018  | 2018-09-01 |  Sutisna | 6`

and i want to make it like this :

`LetterNumber | DateLetter | ToLetter | Row
AA-010-2018  | 2018-09-01 |  Jon     | 1
AA-010-2018  | 2018-09-01 |  Dian    | 2
AA-010-2018  | 2018-09-01 |  Jajang  | 3
BB-011-2018  | 2018-09-01 |  Julaeha | 1
BB-011-2018  | 2018-09-01 |  Endang  | 2
BB-011-2018  | 2018-09-01 |  Sutisna | 3`

how can i achieve it in sql lite ?

thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Sqlite 3.25 or better, you can use the `row_number()` window function:

```
SELECT LetterNumber
     , DateLetter
     , ToLetter
     , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY LetterNumber) AS Row
FROM your_table
ORDER BY LetterNumber;
```

Comment: sorry late response, i'm using old version....so theres no way it can access row_number() window fuction...